# how to make my site multi tenant

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, multi-tenant

I have build an helpdesk system in php and I have 3 different sites which needs that helpdesk system but I want my helpdesk system to be multi-tenant for the 3 sites.
and also what I want to have is that I have a superAdmin having his control over all three sites and three 3 different admins which will control thier own site.
How this can be done.. I searched a lot, I found wordpress having multi tenant facility, but dont understand how wordpress is doing this.
Guide me in this direction

Comment: [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: my tries:-'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451074/unable-to-access-to-the-dashboard-of-tenant-sites' but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Check out the following in regards to a [WordPress Multi-tenant solution](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/wordpress-multitenancy/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about word press or anything. What I think is why don't you host this help desk in forth site and redirect all the three sites while the user needs help desk?

Comment: Yep I thought this before but all three different sites contains three different things and user is supposed to see and get help only to that thing from which site he is referring to help-desk. I need an superAdministrator which manages all three help-desk site context.. are you getting my point..

Comment: I am not an expert and I don't have experience in this area. So don't expect from me much. But I think you may use frames. Put the help desk as a seperate site and add the required page inside a frame of your original three sites. So the the user can see your help desk as a part of your sites.

Comment: Does your helpdesk system supports tickets? or is it only the help materials?

Comment: @Balakumaran : thanks for the reply, but what I want to have is that I have a superAdmin who has control over all three sites and three 3 different admins which will control thier own site.

Comment: @Nish yes there is the facility of raising tickets along with the knowledge base which is for providing help material